# C Macro get token value instead of token name

Tags: c, macros, concatenation, c-preprocessor

Please see the code snipped, in c, below and look at the comments. Is there anyway to make this possible? Does the preprocessor already know that spn_1 = 18? Is there anyway to use the value of spn_1 as a token name?

```
#define TEST_M(_spn) struct astruct _test_struct_##_spn = { .spn = _spn, };

enum spns {
    spn_1 = 18,
};

struct astruct {
    int spn;
};

TEST_M(spn_1)

// What I want:
// struct astruct _test_struct_18 = { .spn = 18, };
// What I get:
// struct astruct _test_struct_spn_1 = { .spn = 18, };
// I can do, but I want attach a name to 18:
// TEST_M(18)
```

Comment: An enum is not a pre-processor constant so you can't have it expanded to an integer constant at the pre-processor stage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want the preprocessor to replace a token by its value, you need the preprocessor for this. So the first step is to use `#define` instead of an enumeration.

But because of the sequence that macros are expanded, the second step is to use an intermediate macro.

```c
#define TEST_M2(_spn) struct astruct _test_struct_##_spn = { .spn = _spn, };
#define TEST_M(_spn) TEST_M2(_spn)

#define SPN_1 18

struct astruct {
    int spn;
};

TEST_X(SPN_1)
TEST_X(18)
```

This also works with literal numbers.

With GCC you can check the resulting source if you use its option "-E".